# Compare "if between" with bitwise operators instead of logical

Tags: c, binary, compare, bit-manipulation

Okay i know this is a pretty mean task from which i got nightmares but maybe ..i'll crack that code thanks to someone of you.

I want to compare if number is between 0 and 10 with bitwise operators. Thats the thing.. it is between 0 and 10 and not for example between 0 and 2, 0 and 4, 0 and 8 and so on..

Reference for number/binary representation with 0-4 bits. (little endian)

0   0

1   1

2   10

3   11

4   100

5   101

6   110

7   111

8   1000

9   1001

10  1010

---

11  1011

12  1100

13  1101

14  1110

15  1111

---

Trying to figure out something like
if(((var & 4) >> var) + (var & 10))

Comment: Is there a minimum or maximum possible input?

Comment: There is only a variable that could be anything.

Comment: Ok. So your first step could be to make sure it's 1-15. So you could bitwise and with 15 and that can rule out everything greater than 15. It's a start :).

Comment: The rules of these interview questions are never clear.  Can you use `==`?  Can you use `||`?  Can you use the ternary operator?  Can you use `return`???

Comment: @pat umm.. like i said not using logical operators but only bitwise operators. You can't use return.

Comment: Seems like a [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) problem. What sort of job were you interviewing for?

Comment: I don't get the question.

Comment: The question requires an arcane combination of knowledge. So I was curious to know where the question came from.

Comment: A race for programmers in my county. The winner of all the puzzles receives a great prize and stuff.

Comment: Ah, that would explain it.

Comment: There must be a smart way for it. It might require a lot of code and math.. no horrific clue. I am near explosion. But i've seen people doing similar stuff. I think we have to find whats unique in the binary between 0 and 10 comparing to a specific number/formule.

Comment: So you can use addition?  That's not a bitwise operator!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that addition is allowed, then:

```
(v & ~0xf) | ((v+5) & ~0xf)
```

is non-zero if `v` is out-of-range.  The first term tests if `v` is outside the range 0..15, and the second shifts the unwanted `11, 12, 13, 14, 15` outside the 0..15 range.

Comment: Isn't there a way to make it in the scope of 0-10?

Comment: I don't understand, all of the examples I gave test for the range 0-10

Comment: I think that might work. I will try it out tomorrow since now i am in a really really bad condition. Arithmetic and bitwise comparison operators are allowed. `== != ! && || < >` are not allowed.

Comment: Sorry wanted to type out the shift operators too `>>` and `<<` instead, but it didn't let me edit on time..

Comment: Yes! It works like that. It would be also faster if it wasn't the `v+5` part and it would be suggested in real practice instead of the logical comparison. Nicely done! You must be a cyborg or something.

Answer (score 2):

I attempt to solve it with bitwise operators only (**no addition**).

The expression below will evaulate to nonzero if the number (`v`) is out of the 0 - 10 inclusive range:

```
(v & (~0xFU)) |
( ((v >> 3) & 1U) & ((v >> 2) & 1U) ) |
( ((v >> 3) & 1U) & ((v >> 1) & 1U) & (v & 1U) )
```

The first line is nonzero if the number is above 15 (any higher bit than the first four is set). The second line is nonzero if in the low 4 bits it is between 12 and 15 inclusive. The third line is nonzero if in the low 4 bits the number is either 11 or 15.

It was not clear in the question, but if the number to test is limited between the 0 - 15 inclusive range (only low 4 bits), then something nicer is possible here:

```
  ((~(v >> 3)) & 1U) |
( ((~(v >> 2)) & 1U) & (( ~v      ) & 1U) ) |
( ((~(v >> 2)) & 1U) & ((~(v >> 1)) & 1U) )
```

First line is 1 if the number is between 0 and 7 inclusive. Second line is 1 if the number is one of 0, 2, 8 or 10. Third line is 1 if the number is one of 0, 1, 8 or 9. So OR combined the expression is 1 if the number is between 0 and 10 inclusive. Relating this solution, you may also check out the [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map), which can assist in generating these (and can also be used to prove there is no simpler solution here).

I don't think I could get any closer stricly **using only bitwise operators** in a reasonable manner. However if you can use addition it becomes a lot simpler as Pat's solution shows it.

Comment: The second line would seem to be nonzero for any number from 4 to 15.

Comment: As I mentioned on the top, it returns the inverse! (So nonzero if it is *out* of range). I don't think if it is reasonalby doable otherwise with strictly only bitwise operators since masking the range above 15 is not something nice that way (with a set of shifts it is possible, see the bit twiddling hacks page I linked). I added a solution for 4 bit numbers meanwhile, where it is possible to be all clean and correct.

Comment: I don't think i have drill enough power from the universe yet now to comprehend this twiddling ultimate googolplexian orbitarium hack.
But i will test your code again and if really does the job without addition then i assume its better. But still.. more operations to do and it will be slower then pat's bit of code.

Comment: Damn, I did not notice what user3386109 mentioned. It is taken: don't code messy logic without verifying it three times that it gives the intended result. And test it. Anyway, I checked the stuff with a Karnaugh map, and (after fixing up stuff) it also reinforces that there is no simpler way with only bitwise ops.

Comment: here's an [online Karnaugh map solver](http://www.32x8.com/circuits4_____A-B-C-D_____m_0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10___________option-0_____899788975371824592721)

Answer (score 0):

When addition is allowed and the range is 0..15, a simple solution is

```
(v - 11) & ~7
```

which is nonzero when v is in the range 0..10. Using shifts instead, you can use

```
(1<<10) >> v
```

which is also nonzero if the input is in the range 0..10. If the input range is unrestricted and the shift count is modulo 32, like on most CPUs, you can use

```
((1<<11) << ~v) | (v & ~15)
```

which is nonzero if the input is *not* in the range (the opposite is difficult since already v == 0 is difficult with only bitops). If other arithmetic operations are allowed, then

```
v / 11
```

can be used, which is also nonzero if the input is not in the range.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool b1 = CheckCycleStateWithinRange(cycleState, 0b0, 0b1010); // Note *: 0b0 = 0 and 1010 = 10

bool CheckCycleStateWithinRange(int cycleState, int minRange, int maxRange) const
{
   return ((IsGreaterThanEqual(cycleState, minRange) && IsLessThanEqual(cycleState, maxRange)) ? true : false );
}

int IsGreaterThanEqual(int cycleState, int limit) const
{
   return ((limit + (~cycleState + 1)) >> 31 & 1) | (!(cycleState ^ limit));
}

int IsLessThanEqual(int cycleState, int limit) const
{
   return !((limit + (~cycleState + 1)) >> 31 & 1) | (!(cycleState ^ limit));
}
```